# Scheduling reminder e-mails in Woocommerce Bookings plugin using Cron events

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cron

I couldn't really find a similar issue so here it goes (apologies in advance for the length):

We use the **Woocommerce Bookings plugin** to let customers make bookings via a Wordpress website. However, the reminder email in Woocommerce is always set to 1 day and this cannot be changed (easily). Because Woocommerce does not offer a simple method for changing the reminder days, we decided to try (re-)scheduling the reminder using cron events instead.

So with the code below, we tried scheduling the reminder for each new booking 2 days in advance instead of 1:

```
add_action('woocommerce_booking_confirmed',  'onReservationConfirmed', 2, 2);
add_action('woocommerce_booking_paid', 'onReservationConfirmed', 1, 2);

function onReservationConfirmed($reservationId, $reservation)
{
  error_log('booking paid / confirmed');
  // get_current_reminder_days() gets the saved value from the db
  $days_before_reminder_is_sent = get_current_reminder_days();

  // calculate time when reminder should be scheduled based on when the event starts
  $timezone_addition = -wc_booking_timezone_offset();
  $event_start = $reservation->all_day ? strtotime( 'midnight', $reservation->start ) : $reservation->start;
  $scheduled_time = $timezone_addition + strtotime( '-' . absint( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_remind_before_days', $days_before_reminder_is_sent ) ) . ' day', $event_start );

  // check if a cron event for this reminder already exists and if so uneschedule it
  $next_event_timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'wc-booking-reminder', array($reservationId ));
    if ( $next_event_timestamp ) {
    error_log('exists' . $next_event_timestamp);
    wp_unschedule_event($next_event_timestamp, 'wc-booking-reminder', array($reservationId), true);
    }

  // schedule reminder at desired time
  wp_schedule_single_event( $scheduled_time , 'wc-booking-reminder', array( $reservationId ) );
}
```

Now, the event definitely fires but:

- **when it changes to status paid**, no $next_event_timestamp is found (which makes sense and is as expected) but it schedules the cron event *1 day in advance and NOT 2 days*.
- **when it changes to status confirmed**, a $next_event_timestamp is found and if I log out whether or not wp_uneschedule_event returns true (which according to [their docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unschedule_event/), it should if it was successfully unscheduled) it does - meaning that it must have unscheduled something before then scheduling a new event. Except, this *event is also scheduled 1 day in advance and NOT 2 days*.

In both cases I logged out the timezone and the reservation id, and both they and the name of the hook match that of the scheduled cron event.

Now the funny thing is:

- **if I cancel the booking**, and then **confirm it again**, it will again fire the event but this time, it *will in fact schedule the cron event as intended* - 2 days in advance.

The only difference that I can think of is that after canceling the booking, there is no existing cron event to unschedule so there is definitely no 'duplicate event created within 10 minutes' which, as [their docs state](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/), would cancel out a newly scheduled event with identical $args.

But then again, should that not **also be the case** in the first case, where it changes to status paid?

I assume that somewhere in the WP code, something else triggers the scheduling of this initial event, but I genuinely do not know how to fix this or test for it.

Can anyone help? Is something wrong with our code? Am I misreading the docs? Do I need to call the functions differently somehow?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't use WordPress cron scheduling, because it is completely unreliable, try to use **[Action Scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/)** plugin that is a scalable, traceable job queue for background processing…
Note that [Action Scheduler library](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler) is included / used by *WooCommerce and WooCommerce Subscriptions and some other huge plugins.*
The documentations is on [ActionScheduler.org](https://actionscheduler.org/)

Comment: did you ever try - add_filter( 'woocommerce_bookings_remind_before_days', create_function( '', 'return 2;' ) ); ?

Comment: We did but it never fires at all - does that work for you?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec okay so I tried using the Action Scheduler, but a cron task will be scheduled regardless - so how do I unschedule that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to change the reminder-sent-date for Woo Bookings. This little piece of code does the trick:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_bookings_remind_before_days', function() {
    return 3;
});
```

Give it a try!